# Unable to retrieve User data from Parse database with query

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfuser

I'm unable to retrieve any user data from the parse database with two query methods. I can get all currentUser data quite easily; however, can't seem to successfully retrieve data from other users. I have a feeling it's quite a simple fix that I'm looking over but I've tinkered with my code for a while now and still returning nil for each variable.

First query method:

```
let userQuery = PFQuery(className: "User")
       userQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: username)
   userQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (users, error) -> Void in
      if error == nil {
        if let objects = users {
            for object in objects {
                if let user = object as? PFUser {

                    self.userBio = user.objectForKey("bio") as! String
                    if user.objectForKey("icon") != nil {
                        self.userIcon = user.objectForKey("icon") as! PFFile
                    }
                    if user.objectForKey("header") != nil {
                    self.headerFile = user.objectForKey("header") as! PFFile
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Second query method:

```
let userQuery = PFUser.query()
       userQuery?.whereKey("username", equalTo: username)
   userQuery!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (users, error) -> Void in
      if error == nil {
        if let objects = users {
            for object in objects {
                if let user = object as? PFUser {

                    self.userBio = user.objectForKey("bio") as! String
                    if user.objectForKey("icon") != nil {
                        self.userIcon = user.objectForKey("icon") as! PFFile
                    }
                    if user.objectForKey("header") != nil {
                    self.headerFile = user.objectForKey("header") as! PFFile
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I think it might be because the security of the User class is set differently by default... You have to change, you can do it in the parse dashboard

Comment: @JVS got it to work using "_User"! Thanks man

Comment: I will put my comment as an answer under your post. If you like, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let userQuery = PFQuery(className: "User")
```

needs to be changed into

```
let userQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
```

since the user class of Parse.com is a special class. and it's name is by default spelled with an underscore.